# FileReader & FileWriter issues (cordova 2.0.0 js)

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I've been working on this bit of PhoneGap (cordova-2.0.0.js) code for an Android* device to persist some data. I'm getting this weird error code and the file doesn't seem to be getting written. I started with the example code and could write an inline string to a file handle successfully, so I'm sure my permissions and all are correct.

Perhaps I'm not handling all the callbacks correctly? There are a lot to listen for! It could be something with truncate(0); I had a hard time finding much documentation on it. Do I need to call window.requestFileSystem more than once? I do it 2x to register different callbacks. If not this, what is causing the error?

Suggestions on reducing the total number of lines for a Read + Write operation will be gladly accepted as well...

*Emulator running Android 2.3.4

here's my code:

```
var CREDENTIALS_FILE_NAME = "credentials.json";
var credentials;

// INIT -- Wait for PhoneGap to load
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, initCredentialReader, fail);
}
function initCredentialReader(fileSystem) {
    fileSystem.root.getFile(CREDENTIALS_FILE_NAME, {create: true}, gotFileEntryReader, fail); 
}
function gotFileEntryReader(fileEntry) {
    fileEntry.file(gotFileToRead, fail);
}
function gotFileToRead(file){
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function(e) {
        console.log("--FILE READER: "+e.target.result);

        if( e.target.result.length < 1 ) {
            credentials = newCredentials();
        } else {
            credentials = JSON.parse( e.target.result );
        }
    };
    reader.readAsText(file);
}
// END CHAIN

function initCredentialWriter(fileSystem) {
    fileSystem.root.getFile(CREDENTIALS_FILE_NAME, {create: true}, gotFileEntryWriter, fail); 
}
function gotFileEntryWriter(fileEntry) {
    fileEntry.createWriter(gotFileWriter, fail);
}
function gotFileWriter(writer) {
    writer.onwrite = function(e) {
        console.log("--- write success");
    };
    var toWrite = JSON.stringify(credentials);
    console.log("--- toWrite: "+toWrite);
    writer.truncate(0);
    writer.seek(0);
    writer.write(toWrite);
}


function fail(error) {
    console.log("--- write FAIL: "+error.code);
}

function newCredentials() {
    console.log("returning newCredentials!");
    return {
        "username" : "",
        "password" : "",
        "organization" : "",
        "cookieValue" : "" };
}

function getCredentials() {
    console.log("--- getCredentials: "+credentials);
    return credentials;
}

function saveCredentials( jsonCredentials ) {
    console.log('--- saveCredentials jsonCredentials: '+ jsonCredentials);

    credentials = JSON.stringify( jsonCredentials );
    console.log('--- credentials to save: '+credentials)

    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, initCredentialWriter, fail);
    return credentials;
}
```

### ERROR

> 08-14 18:41:38.839: I/Web Console(2678): Error in success callback:
>   File9 =
>   {"code":7,"line":2863,"expressionBeginOffset":91407,"expressionEndOffset":91455,"sourceId":4122528,"sourceURL":"file:///android_asset/www/cordova-2.0.0.js"}
>   at file:///android_asset/www/cordova-2.0.0.js:258

Answer (score 1):

So, turns out that calling truncate() and write() is not asynchronously correct-- just had implement more callbacks, like so:

```
function initCredentialTruncate(fileSystem) {
    fileSystem.root.getFile(CREDENTIALS_FILE_NAME, {create: true}, gotFileEntryTruncate, fail); 
}
function gotFileEntryTruncate(fileEntry) {
    fileEntry.createWriter(gotFileTruncate, fail);
}
function gotFileTruncate(writer) {
    writer.onwrite = function(e) {
        console.log("--- truncate success");
    };
    writer.truncate(0);
    //writer.seek(0);
}
// END CHAIN
```

and call the init function when necessary. thx for letting me vent, StackOverflow...